# Read text from new window with powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make a powershell script that would open up a new IE window from javascript link and I would like to read a text from that new window. So far, the script would only read the content from original IE window and I'm not sure how to get the script to read content off from new IE page.

```
    $ie = new-object -com InternetExplorer.Application 

    $ie.navigate("https://www.testsite.com/") 

    do {sleep 1} until (-not ($ie.Busy)) 

    $ie.visible = $true  

    $doc = $ie.document

    if ($ie.document.documentelement.innerText.Contains('Welcome') -eq "True") {
        "Site is RUNNING"
    } else {
        "Site is STOPPED"   
    }

    $link = @($ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A')) | Where-Object {$_.innerText -eq 'Click here for new site'}

    $link.click()

    if ($ie.document.documentelement.innerText.Contains('New Page') -eq "True") {
        "Site is RUNNING"
    } else {
        "Site is STOPPED"   
    }
```

New window pops up after $link.click(), and I don't know how to read anything from the new window. I could read the text from original www.test.com/ page but not from the new page.

Thank you.

PT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to iterate over all IE windows/tabs and select the one with the title you're looking for:

```
$title = '...'

$ie2 = (New-Object -COM 'Shell.Application').Windows() | ? {
  $_.Name -eq 'Windows Internet Explorer' -and $_.LocationName -eq $title
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to use the same concept to create separate shell.application and grab output from that window.